# Fundamental Period of a Summation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, summation

[image]

How would I find the fundamental period of a summation such as this one? Any hints/suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing something about the constants, you cannot determine the *fundamental* period. For example, if $A_n=0$ for all $n$, you get $f(t)=0$ which has no smallest period and thus no fundamental period.

However, you can find a period for your function $f$, and the fundamental period, if any, will be a part (one-half, one-third, one-fourth, etc.) of that period. Use the facts that all the exponents are multiples of $j\omega_0t$ and $e^{jt}$ has its own fundamental period. Whoever is asking you this question probably means you to find this period: they are mistaken about it necessarily being the fundamental period, though in most cases it will be.

---

If you increase the value of $t$ by $\dfrac{2\pi}{\omega_0}$, then all the exponents are increased by a multiple of $2\pi j$, the terms are multiplied by powers of $e^{2\pi j}=1$ and are thus not changed. Therefore $\dfrac{2\pi}{\omega_0}$ is a period of $f(t)$. However, it may not be the fundamental period, depending on the particular $A_n$.

Comment: A_n won't equal 0 though. How would I find the period of the summation?

Comment: @smd: What else do you know about the $A_n$? That matters. Again, finding *a period* from your expression is easy. You probably are supposed to do that.

Comment: Nothing, I just know A_n = 1, 2, ... and it's a complex constant

Comment: @smd: What you just wrote is not what the original question says. In fact, if the $A_n$ are all positive integers, the series will not converge. The original question says that the $n$ are positive integers. It seems to be badly stated.

Comment: what I wrote is what the question states at the bottom. Regardless of how poor the question is stated, I need to find the period and I'm still unsure how to go about doing so

Comment: If for some positive integer $k>1$ we have $A_n\ne 0 \iff k|n$, then $2\pi/k\omega_0$ is a period of $f$. But if $A_n\ne 0\iff n=1$ then the fundamental period of $f$ is $2\pi/\omega_0$ .. So we cannot determine the fundamental period of $f$ without more information.