# How to compute the fundamental period of a linear combination of harmonically related complex exponentials?

Tags: fourier-series, signal-processing

Given reals numbers $a_k$ for $k\in\{1,\ldots,N\}$, how do I prove that the fundamental period (the smallest positive $T>0$ for which $x(t)=x(t+T)$) of

$x_N(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_k e^{j\omega_0 k t}$

is $T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega_0}$ when $a_1\neq 0$?

This question is identical to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628190/fundamental-period-of-a-summation), but the answer there does not help since I am not looking for "a period" but rather the fundamental period.

EDIT: The question follows from my reading of the book "Signals and Systems" (Prentice Hall, 1996) by Alan V. Oppenheim, Alan S. Willsky, and S. Hamid, which states the following in pages 186-187.

"A linear combination of harmonically related complex exponentials of the form
$$x(t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_k e^{jk\omega_0t}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_k e^{jk(2\pi/T)t}$$
is also periodic with period $T$."

It is easy to verify that $T$ is a period of $x(t)$, and even though it seems quite obvious that $T$ should also be the fundamental period, I am not quite able to put together a proof of that. So far, here's the closest I have gotten to a proof.
To be clear, I will consider only the problem of proving that $x_N(t)$ is periodic with fundamental period $T$ when $a_1\neq 0$.

Suppose that $x_N(t)$ is periodic with period $\tau>0$. My goal is to show that the smallest $\tau$ satisfying $x_N(t)=x_N(t+\tau)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ is equal to $T$.
Since $x_N(t)=x_N(t+\tau)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x_N$ is smooth (it is continuously differentiable everywhere up to an arbitrary order), then
$$\begin{gather*}
x_N(t) =x_N(t+\tau)\\
x_N'(t) =x_N'(t+\tau)\\
\vdots\\
x_N^{(N-1)}(t)=x_N^{(N-1)}(t+\tau)
\end{gather*}$$
and, in particular, we have that
$$\begin{gather*}
x_N(0) =x_N(\tau)\\
x_N'(0) =x_N'(\tau)\\
\vdots\\
x_N^{(N-1)}(0)=x_N^{(N-1)}(\tau)
\end{gather*}$$

Since $$x_N^{(n)}(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{N}a_k(jk\omega_0)^ne^{j\omega_0kt}$$
it follows that
$$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & \ldots & 1\\
j\omega_0 & 2j\omega_0 & \ldots & Nj\omega_0\\
(j\omega_0)^2 & (2j\omega_0)^2 & \ldots & (Nj\omega_0)^2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
(j\omega_0)^{N-1} & (2j\omega_0)^{N-1} & \ldots & (Nj\omega_0)^{N-1}
\end{bmatrix}}_{M}\begin{bmatrix}
(1-e^{j\omega_0\tau})a_1\\
(1-e^{2j\omega_0\tau})a_2\\
\vdots\\
(1-e^{Nj\omega_0\tau})a_N
\end{bmatrix}=0.$$
If $M$ is nonsingular then the desired result follows, but how do I show that? Also, it seems that there could be a much more obvious answer to my question.

EDIT 2: The matrix $M$ can be decomposed as follows.
$$M=\text{diag}([1\ j\omega_0\ \ldots\ (j\omega_0)^{N-1}]^\top)\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & \ldots & 1\\
1 & 2 & \ldots & N\\
1 & 2^2 & \ldots & N^2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & 2^{N-1} & \ldots & N^{N-1}
\end{bmatrix}}_{S}$$
where $\text{diag}(v)$ is a $N\times N$ diagonal matrix, i.e., a square matrix whose diagonal entries are the elements of $v\in\mathbb{R}^N$ and every other entry is equal to $0$. It is immediately obvious that $M$ is singular when $\omega_0=0$, in which case $x_N$ does not have a fundamental period.
If $\omega_0\neq 0$, then $M$ is nonsingular if and only if $S$ is nonsingular.

Through computations, I found out that $S$ can be decomposed as $S=LDU$ (for all $N$ up to 11 at least), where $L$ is a lower triangular matrix $L=[\ell_{mn}]_{1\leq m,n N}$ where $\ell_{mn}$ is the [Stirling coefficient of the 2nd kind $S(m,n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), $D=[d_{mn}]_{1\leq m,n\leq N}$ is a diagonal matrix where the entries of the diagonal are given by the [Pochhammer symbol](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html) $d_{nn}=\text{Pochhammer}(1,m-1)$ for each $1\leq n\leq N$, and $U=[u_{mn}]_{1\leq m,n\leq N}$ is an upper triangular matrix satisfying $u_{mn}=\Gamma(m,n-m+1)/\Gamma(m,1)$ with
$$\Gamma(m,k)=\Pi_{i=1}^{m-1}(k+i-1).$$

For example, for $N=4$ we have

$$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
     1  &   1 &    1 &    1\\
     1  &   2 &    3 &    4\\
     1  &   4 &    9 &   16\\
     1  &   8 &   27 &   64
\end{bmatrix}}_{S}=\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
     1  &   0 &    0 &    0\\
     1  &   1 &    0 &    0\\
     1  &   3 &    1 &   0\\
     1  &   7 &    6 &   1
\end{bmatrix}}_{L}\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
     1  &   0 &    0 &    0\\
     0  &   1 &    0 &    0\\
     0  &   0 &    2 &   0\\
     0  &   0 &    0 &   6
\end{bmatrix}}_{D}\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
     1  &   1 &    1 &    1\\
     0  &   1 &    2 &    3\\
     0  &   0 &    1 &   3\\
     0  &   0 &    0 &   1
\end{bmatrix}}_{U}$$

I have only tested this conjecture numerically, but if it holds for all $N$, then this would answer my question. However, it does leave open the questions: **why** does $S$ have this peculiar decomposition? Are there simpler answers to my original question?

Comment: Hint: $a_1e^{j\omega_0t}$ has period $T$ and there is no smaller period.

Comment: On the contrary, every other complex exponential has smaller period. Also, the sum of two periodic signals can have smaller period than the two.

Comment: Do you know that matrix $S$ belongs to a family called Vandermonde matrices ? I am not certain at all I have already seen the very interesting decomposition you give of this matrix.

Comment: @JeanMarie I did not know that. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: See [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X07001412?via%3Dihub) where you will find your example at the end of paragraph 2.